# Is there a way to instantiate this class with dot syntax?

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript class/instantiation/method call:

```
var myClass = function(a){
    var myElement = a,
        myMethod = function(){
            alert(myElement.html());
        }

    return {
        myMethod: myMethod
    }
}

var myObj = new myClass($('#elementA'));
myObj.myMethod();
```

And my markup:

```
<div id="elementA">This is the text in elementA</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/WybQb/).

Is there a way to instantiate this class with dot syntax? Ideally, it would look like: `myObj.myClass()`? Identical to how jquery instantiates new widgets (`$().tabs();` comes to mind). Would I need to restructure my object? If so, how?

If you can infer that I am misunderstanding how any part of this works, please feel free to correct me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: have a look at how jquery plugins do it: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would go about something like this:

```
var myObj = {

    myMethod: function(elem) {

        alert($(elem).html()); //do your alert
        return this; //return the object for chanining

    },

    myOtherMethod: function() {

        alert("This is something other method");
        return this;    

    }

}

myObj.myMethod("#elementA").myOtherMethod();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LqvXg/

Just create a new object with the `var` name of whatever you want.

If you're going to use `new`, you should probably use it with a constructor.  You could also use `Object.create()` and pass the prototype.

The only time I return an object with methods is when I am using closures and I have variables that need to change...  A perfect example would be something like a timer.

Answer (score 0):

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WybQb/2/

What is wrong with just chaining all of it? Though, if you intend on doing things like this... I'm going to get shot down for suggesting this, but this syntax might be awesome for you:

```
var myClass = function(a){
    var myElement = a,
       myMethod = function(){
        alert(a.html());
       }

    return {
       myMethod: function() { return new myMethod(); }
   }
}
```

The only benefit of this is to avoid the `new` keyword.